# getting value from unordered list of dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, oracle

I have a question regarding retrieving db value from database, showed them in an unordered list and passing to the other dropdown list, so my code is

```
 <?php         
        $projectParse = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT_NAME FROM FABRICATION');
        oci_execute($projectParse);

        echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></strong> <strong> &nbsp PROJECT</strong> <b class="caret"></b></a>';
        echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';

        while($row = oci_fetch_array($projectParse,OCI_ASSOC)){
            $project = $row['PROJECT_NAME'];
        echo "<li id='project'>$project</li>";
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

So the problem with this is, i can pull down the values in the dropdown but i cant click them.
and once the value is clicked it passes to the jquery,

```
$(function(){
    // SHOW RECORD
    $('#project').change(function(){
        $.post('update_fabrication.php',
                            {action: "show", method:"POST",
                             proj:$('#project').val()}
                             );     
    });
});
```

and use the values for the second database

```
$result = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT DISTINCT HEAD_MARK FROM FABRICATION WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :projName');
             oci_bind_by_name ($result, "projName", $_POST["project"]);
             oci_execute($result);

             echo '<label><SELECT name="headmark" id="headmark" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Select Project">'.'<br>';
             echo '<OPTION VALUE=" ">'."Project Select".'</OPTION>';

             while($row = oci_fetch_array($result,OCI_ASSOC)){
             $HM = $row ['HEAD_MARK'];
             echo "<OPTION VALUE='$HM'>$HM</OPTION>";
             }
             echo '</SELECT></label><br />';
```

Please help me with my situation is and any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using some sort of plugin to create those lists into a `<select>` element?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do:

1) Your `<ul>` needs the `id` tag, not each `<li>`. *Remember `id` is unique to every element and it should not repeat.*

```
echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="project">';
```

2) The `<li>` need to contain anchor tags inside so that the click function can be performed, so change to:

```
while($row = oci_fetch_array($projectParse,OCI_ASSOC)){
    $project = $row['PROJECT_NAME'];
    echo '<li><a href="#">$project</a></li>';
}
```

3) Since `$project` is a text now, you need to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the inside value of the `<a>`:

```
$('#project li a').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    $.post('update_fabrication.php',
    {
     action: "show", method:"POST",
     proj:val
    });     
});
```

Short **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y7ht9/)**

Comment: so i did exactly what u suggested and its awesome, the problem is i cant pass the value to the second dropdown. and the second dropdown shows nothing.

Comment: here is the report from firebug,

Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
action  : show
project :
Source  :
action=show&project=

and my jQuery is,
` $('#project li a').click(function(){
                        $.post('update_fabrication.php',
                                {action: "show", 
                                 project:$('#project li a').val()}
                                 );
                });`

Comment: @Chriskonz If you want the value to appear in address, you should use `$.get`.

Comment: i tried to modify with $.get but it still doesnt work. I am grabbing the value with this statement oci_bind_by_name($result, "projName", $_POST["project"]); in the same page.

Comment: @Chriskonz In your jQuery, this line `project:$('#project li a').val()` should be `project:$(this).text()`.

Comment: nice i can see the value in Params tab : action show
project POWERHOUSE. but i cant use that 'POWERHOUSE' for the second dropdown list. which is `$result = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT DISTINCT HEAD_MARK FROM FABRICATION WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :projName');
                 
                 oci_bind_by_name($result, "projName", $_POST["project"]);`

Comment: @Chriskonz Did you use `$.get` or `$.post`? Also `echo` the value of `$_POST["project"]`.

Comment: im using $.post 

if you wanna dig deeper here is the code, 
http://pastebin.com/UNRSRRsp.

thanks a lot for helping me. I really appreciate it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52165/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-chriskonz)